# How to use "underscore" module in a nodejs application on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, parse-platform, npm

I have a Node.js application deployed on Heroku.

I need to use the "underscore" module in the "\cloud\main.js".

I have tried the following in the main.js but it was unsuccessful:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

When pushing the changes to git for deployment to Heroku, it failed and gave "Cannot find the module underscore".

What is the correct way to use the **underscore** module in Node.js on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like module **'underscore**' is not on **heroku**.

Update your **package.json** file ,Include '**underscore**' in it.

Open your **package.json**, add following dependency :

```
"dependencies": {    
    "underscore": "*" // Specify required version
  }
```

Now push modified **package.json** back to heroku.

On app startup heroku will automatically fetch the modules specified in **package.json**

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a package.json?  To deploy a nodejs application to heroku, you need to include your dependencies in package.json:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

If you don't have a package.json, you can generate one in your current working directory by running:

`npm init`

After that, install the underscore module with the --save option:

`npm install underscore --save`

Hope this helps!